# jQuery UI 1.7.2 vs jQuery 1.8.5 - do I need to change my 1.7.2 theme created by themeroller?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, themeroller

I am switching to jQuery 1.8.5 and was wondering if there's anything there that might break my jQuery UI 1.7.2 theme created by themeroller. Do I need to create a new theme (because of new effects, etc) or can I just re-use my old CSS files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need new CSS, there are several code changes (and even new widgets) that need updated CSS.

Your current jQuery UI CSS file should have a URL inside a comment, like this:

```
To view and modify this theme, visit http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/?....
```

Just go to that URL to get the updated/current version of your theme, so you don't need to reconfigure colors and such.

Comment: Ah okay. Brilliant Nick. Once again.

Comment: @Scott - updated the answer, I think you'll like the addition ;)